# AppSettings external refresh

Tags: settings, config

I have an external config file for my AppSettings, called ApplicationSettings.sgs.

This file is then in turn, reference in the my web.config as an external file source:

```
<appSettings file="Assets\Settings\application.sgs" />
```

However, when making changes to application.sgs, and I refresh my page where the new value should be pulling through, I still get the old value.

I've ensured that I'm refreshing the section, using `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");` but this is also brings back the default value. Is there something a miss in this solution?

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: Has anyone been able to answer this? I have the same problem.

Comment: BJHuffine. I ended up setting up a filesystemwatcher to check for any file changes. If any changes occur, I clean the class instance, and reinstantiate it with the changes. this is a very long way around, but the only other way I could get it to work. this appears to be a problem within the .net framework specifically. you can try with WebConfigurationManager (inherits from ConfigurationManager) but I couldn't get this to work either.